# Better ways to build a linq specification for querying or is this the only way?

Tags: c#, linq

The code pretty much explains what I am doing here. Just wondering if anyone can think of a better way.

```
public class AttachmentQuery
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AttachmentQuery"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">The type.</param>
    /// <param name="status">The status.</param>
    /// <param name="sort">The sort.</param>
    /// <param name="order">The order.</param>
    /// <param name="page">The page.</param>
    public AttachmentQuery(string type, string status, SortAttachment sort, SortOrder order, int? page)
    {
        IAttachmentSpecification specification = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(type))
        {
            specification = new AttachmentFileTypeSpecification(type);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
        {
            if (specification == null)
            {
                specification = new AttachmentStatusSpecification(status.AsEnum<AttachmentStatus>());
            }
            else
            {
                var spec = new AndSpecification<Attachment>(
                    specification, 
                    new AttachmentStatusSpecification(status.AsEnum<AttachmentStatus>())
                );

                specification = spec as IAttachmentSpecification;
            }
        }

        if (specification == null)
        {
            specification = new AttachmentSpecification();
        }

        specification.Page = page;
        specification.Limit = Setting.AttachmentPageLimit.Value;
        specification.Sort = sort;
        specification.Order = order;

        this.Specification = specification;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the specification.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The specification.</value>
    public IAttachmentSpecification Specification
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/Mike343/Netcoders/blob/master/Coders.Web/Controllers/Administration/Queries/AttachmentQuery.cs).

[How it is used](https://github.com/Mike343/Netcoders/blob/master/Coders.Web/Controllers/Administration/AttachmentController.cs#L60).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would definitely write it differently but exact result depends on whether your `AndSpecification` supports only two parameters or it can accept `IEnumerable` of attachments.

If it has two parameters and you expect to nest those `AndSpecifications` if you will have more specs to compose then I would write something like this:

```
var typeSpecification = string.IsNullOrEmpty(type) ? null : new AttachmentFileTypeSpecification(type);
var statusSpecification = string.IsNullOrEmpty(status) ? null : new AttachmentStatusSpecification(status.AsEnum<AttachmentStatus>());
var specificationsToCompose = new IAttachmentSpecification[] {typeSpecification, statusSpecification};

var composedSpecification = specificationsToCompose
                     .Aggregate((IAttachmentSpecification) null, (accumulator, currentSpec) =>
                         {
                             if (accumulator != null && currentSpec != null) return new AndSpecification<Attachment>(accumulator, currentSpec);
                             return accumulator ?? currentSpec;
                         })
                      ?? new AttachmentSpecification();

...

this.Specification = composedSpecification;
```

Comment: Thats a good idea, I will probably end up trying this out.

Answer (score 3):

How about adding an extension method to IAttachmentSpecification, such as

```
public static class AttachmentSpecificationExtensions
{
     public static IAttachmentSpecification And(this IAttachmentSpecification orig, IAttachmentSpecification spec)
     {
         if (orig is NullAttachmentSpecification))
         {
             return spec ?? orig;
         }

         if (spec == null || spec is NullAttachmentSpecification)
         {
             return orig;
         }

         return (IAttachmentSpecification) new AndSpecification<Attachment>(specification, orig);
     }
}

public class NullAttachmentSpecification : AttachmentSpecification
{
}
```

Now you can write your AttachmentQuery constructor as

```
public AttachmentQuery(string type, string status,
    SortAttachment sort, SortOrder order, int? page)
{
    var statusSpec = string.IsNullOrEmpty(status) 
            ? new NullAttachmentSpecification()
            : new AttachmentStatusSpecification(status.AsEnum<AttachmentStatus>())
    var typeSpec = string.IsNullOrEmpty(type) 
            ? new NullAttachmentSpecification()
            : new AttachmentFileTypeSpecification(type)

    Specification = statusSpec.And(typeSpec);

    Specification.Page = page;
    Specification.Limit = Setting.AttachmentPageLimit.Value;
    Specification.Sort = sort;
    Specification.Order = order;
}
```

It would seem more obvious to me what the intent was here. Plus it would seem more extensible if you add other types of `AttachmentSpecification` later.